# Loop through find and replace for line breaks

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro which finds a string and makes sure that there are always 3 line breaks after the string.

If Chapter One is found, there should always be 3 line breaks after it.
I need to loop through this until this is the case (so if there's 7 line breaks after "Chapter One" it needs to loop through until there are 3.

Unfortunately i'm having difficulty inserting the loop to remove more than 3 consecutive line breaks

```
Sub ChapterLineBreaks()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles( _
        "Heading 1,Chapter Heading")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Chapter One^p^p^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "Chapter One^p^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Expected:

Chapter One

Text should then start here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use wildcards like this:

```
Sub ChapterLineBreaks()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles( _
        "Heading 1,Chapter Heading")
    With Selection.Find
        .text = "(Chapter One)([^13]@)([!^13])"
        .Replacement.text = "\1^p^p^p\3"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

You will find good info [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-or-formatting-in-word-for-mac-ac12f262-e3cd-439a-88a0-f5a59875dcea), [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm), and [here](https://uhasct.com/use-wildcards-to-find-and-replace-in-word/). What I did was use the wildcards to define a regular expression: "Chapter One{1 or more line breaks}Other text". I then replaced the line breaks with exactly 3 line breaks.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Would you mind just explaining the changes you made, and do you have a source for the Wildcards? I've got a couple of other things to do with this but thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. You will find good info [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-or-formatting-in-word-for-mac-ac12f262-e3cd-439a-88a0-f5a59875dcea), [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm), and [here](https://uhasct.com/use-wildcards-to-find-and-replace-in-word/). What I did was use the wildcards to define a regular expression: "Chapter One{1 or more line breaks}Other text". I then replaced the line breaks with exactly 3 line breaks.

Comment: Since on Stack Overflow comments are considered "volatile" (they tend to get deleted over time) the preferred method of adding additional information is to use the Answer's [edit] link to put it in the answer, itself. Note, also, that "Tim" probably was not notified of your reply here in comments. Generally, only the person who posted the Answer (or Question) gets a notification unless you specifically "ping" them by preceding the name with a @, for example: @TimsKillerRabbit

Comment: I was addressing you, AAA. The links and the explanation about using Word wild cards would better be *in the answer*, not in a comment. And Tim probably didn't see the information posted in the comment since you didn't "ping" him (although my ping should reach him).

Comment: I know. It reached "him" because "he" was the OP - the one who asked the question. So I don't need to ping "him"specifically.